# How do I Infer Parameter and Function Types when calling a function from dictionary lookup?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

## Goal and Problem

I have a simple goal of using a wrapper function to retrieve a method from a dictionary and to call that method with the provided payload of the appropriate type. How would I successfully achieve this?

A general outline of one of my attempts is below. It seems that the main issue is that the calling maps[request] returns a union object and I'm not sure how to typecast it to printA if request == "A" or printB if request == "B" without a switch statement (imagine having 100's of different request types).

## Sample Code

```js
function printA (a:string) {
    return a;
}
function printB (a:number) {
    return a;
}

const maps = {
    "A": printA,
    "B": printB
}


function receive<R extends keyof typeof maps>(request:R, payload:Parameters<typeof maps[R]>) {
           maps[request](payload)
}
```

## Error Message

```
Argument of type 'Parameters<{ A: (a: string) => string; B: (a: number) => number; }[R]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    Type '[a: string] | [a: number]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      Type '[a: string]' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
```

Comment: This is very nearly the same as the other question; note though that your example code should probably be using spread/rest on `payload` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmL6Vw), right?  `f(...payload)` if `payload` is of a `Parameters` type